# Need sql query to search in first 10 record

Tags: mysql

Hi i have requirement where 'COUNTRY' table has 100 records i need to search in first 10 records

```
SELECT * FROM `Country` where `LifeExpectancy`>50 LIMIT 10
```

Its giving me 10 records but i want it should search in only first 10 record

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Nested Query` Or `INLINE VIEW` as Below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM `Country` LIMIT 10
) AS T
WHERE `LifeExpectancy`>50
```